# Using data from other columns (UPDATE in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

This is basically a freebie for anyone who is good w/ MySQL, as I've stated before I'm a noob and my searching hasn't turned up what I need yet.

So, column "description" in table salesrule contains a unique customer number, ex: description = 100099, I'd like to set column "name" to read: Code for customer: 100099.

```
    UPDATE salesrule
    SET name = 'Code for customer:' "description"
    WHERE description LIKE '1000%'
```

How do I put the number contained by "description" in to my "name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE salesrule
SET name = CONCAT('Code for customer:', description)
WHERE name LIKE '1000%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Update salesrule
SET name = 'Code for customer:' + description
WHERE description LIKE '1000%'
```